How to Automatically Update Undetected_Chromedriver?
In Ubuntu, I set up the chrome browser to automatically update.  However, I constantly have to upgrade undetected_chromedriver (UC) manually via pip or I get errors that UC does not match the latest chrome version.
Is there a simple way to automatically update UC?  Thank you!
